# What happens to data in buffer on AudioTrack.write()

Tags: android, android-studio, audiotrack

Here is some code that I'm using to generate a continuous sine wave in android studio. The whole thing runs within a thread. My question is: when I call audio.write(), what happens to any data that may still be in the buffer? Does it dump the old samples and write a new set, or does it append the new sample array to the remaining samples?

```
int buffSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sr, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            //create the AudioTrack object
            AudioTrack audio = new AudioTrack(  AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                                                sr,
                                                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                                                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                                                buffSize,
                                                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            //initialise values for synthesis
            short samples[]= new short[buffSize];   //array the same size as buffer
            int amp=10000;                          //amplitude of the waveform
            double twopi = 8.*Math.tan(1.);         //2*pi
            double fr = 440;                        //the frequency to create
            double ph = 0;                          //phase shift
            //start audio
            audio.play();
            //synthesis loop
            while (isRunning)
            {
                fr=440+4.4*sliderVal;

                for (int i=0;i<buffSize;i++)
                {
                        samples[i]=(short)(amp*Math.sin(ph));
                        ph+=twopi*fr/sr;
                }
                audio.write(samples,0,buffSize);
            }
            //stop the audio track
            audio.stop();
            audio.release();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are correctly setting the buffersize based on the device capability-that is very important to minimize latency.

Then you are building buffers and chunking them out to the hardware so they can be heard. There is nothing "in there" per say. Buffers get built, and you then write the whole buffer each time at track.write.

Below is my generateTone routine, much like yours. Called like such with Frequency in Hz and Duration in ms:

```
AudioTrack sound = generateTone(440, 250);
```

And the generateTone class:

```
private AudioTrack generateTone(double freqHz, int durationMs) {
    int count = (int)(44100.0 * 2.0 * (durationMs / 1000.0)) & ~1;
    short[] samples = new short[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i += 2){
        short sample = (short)(Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / (44100.0 / freqHz)) * 0x7FFF);
        samples[i + 0] = sample;
        samples[i + 1] = sample;
    }
    AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100,
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    count * (Short.SIZE / 8), AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
    track.write(samples, 0, count);
    return track;
}
```

AudioTrack is cool because you can create any kind of sound if you have the right algo. Puredata and Csound make it much easier though on Android.

(I wrote a big chapter on Audio in my book Android Software Development- Collection of Practical Projects.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, got me onto the right track. Are there ever cases where synchronization is necessary to ensure that the device has played x samples before writing the next x samples?

Comment: Glad to hear that! Well, you don't have to sync, but you do have to "keep up". If you can't fill the buffersize blocks quickly enough, then you will get skips or drop outs. You know this happens because you can hear it. This is a big problem in Android because of Audio latency problems. Every Android device ever produced has a higher latency than every iOS device produced. Hard to believe, but true. There is a really good Google open source app called AudioBuffersSize that shows capabilities of the device, such as buffersize and samplerate. Then you can set them correctly in your audio app.

Comment: Thanks Mark! I haven't encountered that problem yet. Would it be a good idea to write a seperate, lightweight writeToBuffer thread?

Comment: For sure, that is a good architecture. If you want to see some excellent code architecture, especially if you start doing codecs do encode .mp3 for example, then the open source google Ringdroid app is another great one.